# Angular7: Router-Outlet appends component instead of replacing it

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have tried many solutions but did not find any solution. Even I did not import "BrowserAnimationModule" but still both html pages are showing on the same page.

Please help.

As per my code, Default component is the "AppComponent" and the other is "TwoComponent".

[image]

**Now below is the code -**

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'first-app-test';

}
```

app-component.html

```
<h2>App Component</h2>
<a routerLink="two">TWO</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Second Component**

two.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  templateUrl: './two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two.component.css']
})
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

two.component.html

```
<p>
  Two Component!
</p>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { TwoComponent } from './two/two.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TwoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'two', component: TwoComponent }], { useHash: false }),
    BrowserModule,

  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the `router-outlet` to `app.component.html` so the second component is added into the `app.component` that is the expected behaviour

If you  have three components  say for example a root component `AppComponent`,  and two child components `OneComponent`  and  `TwoComponent`.

The following will be your solution:

**app.componnet.html**

```
<h2>App Component</h2>
<a routerLink="one">ONE</a>
<a routerLink="two">TWO</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
    {
       path: 'one',
       component:OneComponent,

    },
    {
       path: 'two',
       component:TwoComponent

    },
    {
         path: '',
         redirectTo: 'one',
         pathMatch: 'full',

    },
   ]
  },

  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/page-not-found'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**one.component.html**

```
<p>
  One Component!
</p>
```

**two.component.html**

```
<p>
  Two Component!
</p>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```